# Create a scheduled event on Mysql

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures, mysql-event

I have and scheduled event on mysql.

```
CREATE EVENT 'JOB_Act' 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY  12 HOUR
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

DO 
(...)
```

But i can't use current_timestamp. I know that I can set a future day and a hour. But I need to set, the current day and a fixed time. For ex: today + 2 am.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it runs every day - why is the start date important?

Comment: The start date it's not important. I need this event run twice a day. I need to run at 2AM/PM, but I don't know when the administrator will run the script, so I can't set a random future day. I need this run, from the day the event is created.

Comment: Set a random past date.